# Sizeof member variable of a template type-argument

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

I would like to determine the `sizeof` a particular member variable for a struct type that I am passing as a template argument to a function. However, I get an error from the compiler saying that the sizeof operand is illegal (I am using VS2010 with Windows 7).

Consider the following program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

struct MyFloat {
    float val;
    MyFloat(){val=rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.f);};
};
struct MyDouble {
    double val;
    MyDouble(){val=rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.);};
};

template<class T>
void serializeArrayToFile(const std::string &filename, const std::vector<T> &items) {
    const size_t nbytes = sizeof(T::val); // <--- Error C2070
    std::ofstream os(filename.c_str(),std::ios::out+std::ios::binary);
    for(size_t i=0; i<items.size(); ++i)
        os.write((char*)(&items[i].val),nbytes);
    os.close();
};

void main() {
    const int N = 15;
    std::vector<MyFloat> arr_float(N); // Filled randomly by default constructor
    std::vector<MyDouble> arr_double(N); // Filled randomly by default constructor
    serializeArrayToFile<MyFloat>("myfloat_array.dat",arr_float);
    serializeArrayToFile<MyDouble>("mydouble_array.dat",arr_double);
}
```

This generates the following error:
    error C2070: '' : illegal sizeof operand.

Can someone explain why `sizeof(T::val)` is illegal and how I should determine the `sizeof` T::val, considering that the input vector could be empty ?

Comment: The expression under sizeof is not evaluated, so you can safely use `items[0].val`.

Comment: @n.m Interesting, I did not know that. Any idea why this particular `sizeof` expression fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying `sizeof` to a non-static data member named without an object is a C++11 feature; it was introduced into the language in [paper n2253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2253.html). A conforming C++03 compiler will not allow that usage; if possible you should see if you can use a conforming C++11 compiler.

[Note that contrary to that paper, `sizeof(S::m + 42)` is actually allowed in the final C++11 standard; I'm not sure when that was changed.]

The general workaround is to dereference a null pointer (valid in a non-evaluated context):

```
sizeof(((T*) 0)->val)
```

However, you have an object of type `T` available, so can write:

```
sizeof(items.front().val)
```

This is valid even if the vector is empty, because `sizeof` is a non-evaluated context so `front()` will not actually be called.

Comment: "The general workaround is to dereference a null pointer (valid in a non-evaluated context)" -- really?

Comment: @Yakk well, everyone assumes that it is in C++03; c.f. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232 for some discussion. In C++11 of course we have `std::declval`.

Comment: @Yakk The `offsetof` macro in C is typically implemented in [a similar way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof#Implementation).

Comment: @james the standard headers can do whatever they want; they are part of the compiler in a sense.  User code cannot rely on UB if it is not throw-away.  Standard headers can.  If the compiler changes what it does in response to UB, it must change the header.  Auditing every compiler change forever into the future is not practical for user code.